# Nuxt throws 404 on visit nested route with not default locale i18n

Tags: nuxt.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

I'm currently working with Nuxt3 and i18n. I've already set my i18n config like:

```js
{
            lazy: true,
            langDir: "locales",
            strategy: "prefix",
            defaultLocale: "pl-PL",
            locales: [
                {
                    code: "en-US",
                    iso: "en-US",
                    file: "en-US.json",
                    name: "English(US)",
                },
                {
                    code: "pl-PL",
                    iso: "pl-PL",
                    file: "pl-PL.json",
                    name: "Polski(PL)",
                },
            ],
            config: {
                vueI18n: {
                    fallbackLocale: "pl-PL",
                },
            },
        }
```

I finished second level of certain pages directory, it's like:

pages

--offers

----index.vue

----create.vue

There is nothing wrong with pl-PL.json and en-US.json files.

However when I try to visit:

/en-US/offers/create (/en-US/offers/create works correctly)

Nuxt throws 404 page.

Urls '{locale}/' and '{locale}/offers' are fine and translation works as I expect.

Moreover I've noticed that when I change order of objects inside locales array in config file (PL object first) suddenly /en-US/offers/create start to works good but /pl-PL/offers/create stopped and throws 404.

What is the reason of those 404 and how to fix that?